# Cabal: Post Build Hook inside a Sandbox

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-dev, cabal-sandbox

I am creating a simple post-build-hook for Cabal. The problem comes when I try to work in a sandbox. My hook is expecting the compiled code under:

`dist/something`

but when the build happens inside a sandbox the path becomes:

`dist/dist-sandbox-xxxxxxxx/something`

How can I pass or let know to my hook the current used `dist-sandbox` path?

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked on Cabal's bug tracker: https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/2978

If indeed this is the behavior you are seeing, try upgrading your Cabal.